# MVVM WPF Setting Model to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm developing a WPF App using MVVM architecture but I'm having an issue setting a current Model to a ViewModel.

Well, I'm currently trying to set a Model coming from a ViewModel (A:SectionCustomersViewModel) to another one (B:CustomerViewModel) but everytime the "currentModel" (CustomerViewModel's property) is setted it's just null and obviously the binded View to the CustomerViewModel shows nothing in controls.

I have already tried setting the model directly to the ViewModel but that didn't work, so I changed the strategic using a kind of publisher-subscriber pattern but it didn't work either.

It should be mentioned that i have done test with some data dummy to see if the user controls (textbox, combobox, etc.) are setted and effectively they are.

Time to see the code for more clearness (for a clearer and shorter code I just remove no-needed lines).

---

ViewModel A (SectionCustomersViewModel).

```
class SectionCustomersViewModel : ObservableObject, IPageViewModel
{
    private event Action<CustomerModel> CustomerToCustomerViewModel;

    public string Name => "Customers".ToUpper();
    public string Icon => "images/UserGroups_96px.png";

    private IPageViewModel _currentPageViewModel;
    private ICommand _changePageCommand;
    private ICommand _addCustomerCommand;
    private ICommand _editCustomerCommand;

    public SectionCustomersViewModel()
    {
        // Add available pages
        CustomersViewModel = new CustomersViewModel();
        CustomerViewModel = new CustomerViewModel();
        CustomerToCustomerViewModel += (CustomerViewModel as CustomerViewModel).ReceiveCustomer;
        // Set starting page
        CurrentPageViewModel = CustomersViewModel;
    }

    #region Properties

    #region Pages
    public IPageViewModel CustomersViewModel { get; }
    public IPageViewModel CustomerViewModel { get; }
    #endregion

    public IPageViewModel CurrentPageViewModel
    {
        get => _currentPageViewModel;
        set
        {
            if (_currentPageViewModel != value)
            {
                _currentPageViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPageViewModel");
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Commands
    public ICommand BackPageCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_changePageCommand == null)
                _changePageCommand = new CommandHandler(p => ChangeViewModel(p as IPageViewModel), p => p is IPageViewModel);
            return _changePageCommand;
        }
    }

    public ICommand AddCustomerCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_addCustomerCommand == null)
                _addCustomerCommand = new CommandHandler(param => AddCustomer());
            return _addCustomerCommand;
        }
    }

    public ICommand EditCustomerCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_editCustomerCommand == null)
                _editCustomerCommand = new CommandHandler(c => EditCustomer(c as CustomerModel));
            return _editCustomerCommand;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    private void ChangeViewModel(IPageViewModel viewModel) 
        => CurrentPageViewModel = viewModel;

    private void EditCustomer(CustomerModel customer)
    {
        CurrentPageViewModel = CustomerViewModel;
        CustomerToCustomerViewModel?.Invoke(customer);
    }

    private void AddCustomer()
    {
        CurrentPageViewModel = CustomerViewModel;
        CustomerToCustomerViewModel?.Invoke(new CustomerModel());
    }
    #endregion
}
```

View for the ViewModel A

```
<UserControl x:Class="Presentation.View.Customer.SectionCustomersView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Presentation.ViewModel.Customer"
         xmlns:v="clr-namespace:Presentation.View.Customer"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" Height="Auto">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:SectionCustomersViewModel  x:Key="SectionCustomersVM"/>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CustomersViewModel}">
        <v:CustomersView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CustomerViewModel}">
        <v:CustomerView />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource SectionCustomersVM}"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" />
</Grid>
```

---

ViewModel B (CustomerViewModel).

```
class CustomerViewModel : ObservableObject, IPageViewModel
{
    #region Attributes
    private CustomerModel _currentCustomer;
    private AddressModel _currentAddress;
    private ICommand _loadedCustomerCommand;
    private ICommand _saveCustomerCommand;
    #endregion

    #region IPageViewModel's properties
    public string Name => "Customer";
    public string Icon => string.Empty;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public Action<CustomerModel> ReceiveCustomer 
        => SetCustomer;

    public List<CountryModel> Countries => CountryModel.Load();

    public List<ZoneModel> Zones => ZoneModel.Load();

    public List<CustomerGroupModel> CustomerGroups => CustomerGroupModel.Load();

    public CustomerModel CurrentCustomer
    {
        get => _currentCustomer;
        set
        {
            if (value != _currentCustomer)
            {
                _currentCustomer = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentCustomer");
            }
        }
    }

    public AddressModel CurrentAddress
    {
        get => _currentAddress;
        set
        {
            if (value != _currentAddress)
            {
                _currentAddress = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentAddress");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Commands
    public ICommand LoadedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_loadedCustomerCommand == null)
                _loadedCustomerCommand = new CommandHandler(o => LoadExtraData());
            return _loadedCustomerCommand;
        }
    }

    public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_saveCustomerCommand == null)
            {
                _saveCustomerCommand = new CommandHandler(
                    param => SaveCustomer(),
                    param => (CurrentCustomer != null)
                );
            }
            return _saveCustomerCommand;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    private void SetCustomer(CustomerModel customer) 
        => CurrentCustomer = customer;

    private void LoadExtraData()
    {
        //if (CurrentCustomer.Address_id == 0)
        //    return;
        //// Dummy data, just to test if the binding with the view is correctly setted.
        //CurrentAddress = new AddressModel()
        //{
        //    Firstname = "John",
        //    Lastname = "Doe",
        //    Address_1 = "Nowhere",
        //    City = "Somewhere",
        //    Company = "A-Z",
        //    Country_id = 1
        //};
        //// If the currentCustomer is setted here, it works fine.
        //CurrentCustomer = new CustomerModel()
        //{
        //    Firstname = "Some",
        //    Lastname = "One",
        //    Email = "somemail@mail.com",
        //    Telephone = "555-000-000",
        //    Status = true,
        //    Safe = false,
        //    Newsletter = false,
        //    Customer_group_id = 1
        //};
    }

    private void SaveCustomer()
    {
        // You would implement your Product save here
        CurrentAddress.Save();
        CurrentCustomer.Save();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

View for the ViewModel B

```
<UserControl x:Class="Presentation.View.Customer.CustomerView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Presentation.ViewModel.Customer"
         xmlns:v="clr-namespace:Presentation.View.Customer"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
         VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:CustomerViewModel x:Key="CustomerViewModel" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource CustomerViewModel}" />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<!-- Bind UserControl Loaded event to CustomersVM's LoadedCommand -->
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="160*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="32" Height="32"
            Command="{Binding DataContext.BackPageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:SectionCustomersView}}}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext.CustomersViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:SectionCustomersView}}}">
        <Image Source="/Presentation;Component/images/BackArrow_32px.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
    </Button>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontStretch="Expanded" BorderBrush="#FF4C4D5A" Height="37" Margin="67,10,0,0"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Icon}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontStretch="Expanded" Height="37" Margin="154,10,0,0" Foreground="#FF464646"/>
    <Separator Grid.Row="0" Height="20" Margin="10,52,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
        <WrapPanel>
            <GroupBox Header="Detalles" FontFamily="Century gothic" Height="Auto" Width="367" 
                      VerticalContentAlignment="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Grid Margin="0">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Margin="35,10,0,0">
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Firstname" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="auto" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontStretch="Expanded" Height="37" Foreground="#FF464646"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="135"
                        Text="{Binding CurrentCustomer.Firstname}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="35,52,0,0">
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Lastname" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="auto" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontStretch="Expanded" Height="37" Foreground="#FF464646"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="135"
                        Text="{Binding CurrentCustomer.Lastname}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="35,94,0,0">
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Email" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="auto" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontStretch="Expanded" Height="37" Foreground="#FF464646"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="135"
                        Text="{Binding CurrentCustomer.Email}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="35,136,0,0">
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Telephone" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="auto" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontStretch="Expanded" Height="37" Foreground="#FF464646"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="135"
                        Text="{Binding CurrentCustomer.Telephone}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="35,178,0,0">
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Customer Group" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="auto" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontStretch="Expanded" Height="37" Foreground="#FF464646"/>
                        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        Height="23" Width="135"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerGroups}"
                        SelectedValuePath="Customer_Group_ID" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                        SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentCustomer.Customer_group_id}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Header="Domicilio" FontFamily="Century gothic" Height="377" Width="376"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
                <Grid Margin="0">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Margin="35,10,0,0">
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Name" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="auto" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontStretch="Expanded" Height="37" Foreground="#FF464646"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="135"
                        Text="{Binding CurrentAddress.Firstname}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="35,52,0,0">
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Lastname" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="auto" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontStretch="Expanded" Height="37" Foreground="#FF464646"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="135"
                        Text="{Binding CurrentAddress.Lastname}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="35,94,0,0">
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Company" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="auto" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontStretch="Expanded" Height="37" Foreground="#FF464646"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="135"
                        Text="{Binding CurrentAddress.Company}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="35,136,0,0">
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Address" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="auto" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontStretch="Expanded" Height="37" Foreground="#FF464646"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="135"
                        Text="{Binding CurrentAddress.Address_1}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="35,178,10,0">
                        <Label Content="Ciudad" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="auto" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontStretch="Expanded" Height="37" Foreground="#FF464646"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="135"
                        Text="{Binding CurrentAddress.City}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="35,220,10,0">
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Postcode" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="auto" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontStretch="Expanded" Height="37" Foreground="#FF464646"/>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="135"
                        Text="{Binding CurrentAddress.Postcode}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="35,262,0,0">
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Country" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="auto" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontStretch="Expanded" Height="37" Foreground="#FF464646"/>
                        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        Height="23" Width="135"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Country_ID"
                        SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentAddress.Country_id}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="35,304,10,-13">
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Region" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="auto" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontStretch="Expanded" Height="37" Foreground="#FF464646"/>
                        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        Height="23" Width="135" ItemsSource="{Binding Zones}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Zone_ID"
                        SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentAddress.Zone_id}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Header="Otro" FontFamily="Century gothic" Height="auto" Width="Auto" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
                <Grid Margin="0">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10">
                        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxSlider}"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Newsletter" FontSize="16" FontStretch="Expanded" 
                              FontFamily="Century Gothic" Foreground="#FF464646" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="255" Margin="30,8"
                              IsChecked="{Binding CurrentCustomer.Newsletter}"/>
                        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxSlider}" 
                              VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Status" FontSize="16" FontStretch="Expanded" 
                              FontFamily="Century Gothic" Foreground="#FF464646" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="255" Margin="10,8"
                              IsChecked="{Binding CurrentCustomer.Status}"/>
                        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxSlider}" 
                              VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Safe" FontSize="16" FontStretch="Expanded" 
                              FontFamily="Century Gothic" Foreground="#FF464646" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Width="255" Margin="10,8"
                              IsChecked="{Binding CurrentCustomer.Safe}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
        </WrapPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Button Content="Accept" Grid.Row="2" Height="30" 
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
            Width="80" Margin="0,0,10,10"
            Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your application step-by-step?

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado Yes, I have and all I could say is that the Model is correctly setted to the property (CurrentCustomer) but then it loses the reference in some way. I keep trying to figure out what's wrong...

Comment: Are you sure that you're only setting `CustomersViewModel ` and `CustomerViewModel ` inside `SectionCustomersViewModel()`?  Based on your sample code, I don't see why it would be null after instantiating.

Comment: Hi, where did you declare CurrentPageViewModel  property?

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado Absolutely, there aren't extern initializations or any other partial class for the ViewModel. Actually, I'm taking screenshots in debug mode of the whole code to be uploaded and shown later... I'm not crazy! haha.

Comment: @NhanPhan that property has been deleted for having a shorter a clearness code. Maybe would it be a good idea if I leave the whole code including XAML?

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado I would like to leave some pics of the code in debug mode. The execution order is presented as the pics are shown. [link](https://imgur.com/a/uh13mmM)

Comment: I've seen your screenshots and would want you to verify if the instance of the `CustomerViewModel` is the same before and after the `CurrentCustomer` became `null` (Maybe add a Guid field to verify). Also double check the code where you are setting the value for both `CurrentCustomer` and `_currentCustomer`.

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado It seems that `CustomerViewModel` is being instantiated three times. The first one is when the App start, 2nd one is when `SectionCustomersViewModel` is shown and finally when `CustomerViewModel` is shown as well. It weird because the CustomerViewModel's ctor is just referenced once in the whole code. Maybe it's something about the lifecycle... keep inquiring.

Comment: How are you setting the datacontext for each page/view?

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado they are being setting as a resource from the XAML code.
First, I declare the resource in the UserControl or in Window, and then I just set the resource using UserControl's DataContext property.

`<UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:CustomerViewModel x:Key="CustomerViewModel" />
</UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource CustomerViewModel}" />
    </UserControl.DataContext>`